# Using jQuery .show( ) but the specified div won't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show

I have two divs of class `info-pane`. The first one starts out hidden (`display: none`) and the second has an element which when clicked, is supposed to hide that div and show the first.

**HTML**

```
<div id="infoDiv">
    <div class="info-pane" id="plang">
        <p>Serge Lang</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-pane" id="pvecspace">
        <p id="thatpar"><span name="plang" class="clickable">Lang</span> 1983 p. 109</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the "Lang" portion is clicked, the whole area just goes blank. It doesn't load up the other `info-pane` div. I've done other things with `.hide()` and `.show()` in the past and not had issues, so I don't know what the problem is. My real setup involves PHP and a much more complicated html file, but it doesn't work even in the simplified case.

**JS**

```
function setEventHandlers(){
    $("div[name], p[name], span[name]").click(function ( event ) {
        loadPane(this.name);
    });
}

function loadPane(paneId){

    $('#infoDiv div:not(#' + paneId + ').info-pane').hide();
    $('#' + paneId).show();

}

setEventHandlers();
```

**CSS**

```
#infoDiv {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
span.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#plang {
    display: none;
}
```

### Link to JSFiddle

Here is a (not) working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qn5KX/

I've included in the JSFiddle code I found for `div`-based `console.log()` set up, so you can use that to try and debug it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did not worked because `this.name` doesnt exist in the content.Try this:

```
function setEventHandlers(){
  $("div[name], p[name], span[name]").click(function ( event ) {
        loadPane($(this).attr('name'));
  });}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5KX/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any idea why something like `$(this).get(0).name` doesn't work also?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: because `.get()` does not get attribute of DOM,It is used to Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request. To get/set attributes you need to use `.attr()`

Comment: Actually in the context of jQuery, .get(0) returns the DOM element the first of a jQuery collection of objects. But I just found out that span elements don't have a name attribute accessible through the dot syntax. You have to use, for example, `spanElement.getAttribute('name')`. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes

```
loadPane(this.name);
```

should be:

```
loadPane(this.id);
```

You are using id targetter `#` so you should use its `id` and not its `name`.

Comment: The `name` attribute of the span element is the `id` attribute of another element.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your jquery code into document.ready. Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function setEventHandlers(){
      $("div[name], p[name], span[name]").click(function ( event ) {
          loadPane(this.name);
      });
  }

  function loadPane(paneId){

      $('#infoDiv div:not(#' + paneId + ').info-pane').hide();
      $('#' + paneId).show();

  }

  setEventHandlers();
});
```